# RadComboBox populate with integer values

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

Hi I am trying to populate RadComboBox in dropdown integer values. I tried following ways but it doesnt work.

```
     categoriesCombo.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(2));
```

or

```
RadComboBoxItem item2 = new RadComboBoxItem();
     item2.Text = "Item2";
     item2.Value = 2;
```

In both cases where 2 is intellisense doesnt like that. Because it is suppose to take string. 
Is there a way I can load integer values in the RadComboBox because one index selected I want to read the integer value back.

Comment: what about categoriesCombo.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("2"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Value` is an `object` and `Text` is `string`. Regardless of which you use, you have to convert it to integer while reading.

```
int i=Convert.ToInt32(categoriesCombo.SelectedValue);
```

**Update:**

And make sure that the `value` is not `null` before you attempt to convert it to `int`

Comment: Or use the Int32.TryParse() method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx